# int can't convert non-string with explicit base in for loop with fetchval

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, int, fetch

I am getting more and more confused in python. 
when i try on one row, it works, but when i work on the whole rows of one column, it shows error. 
i want to use the function convert_hex_to_int for each row in the column,
but it shows me the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:/Users/ranic/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line
>   59, in 
>       result_print = (convert_hex_to_int(hex_int, 4))
>   File "C:/Users/r/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 32,
>   in conver
>   t_hex_to_int
>      splitted = [hex(n)[2:][i:i + interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)]  TypeError: 'str' object cannot be
>   interpreted as an integer

here is my code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_VARBINARY, hexToString)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def convert_hex_to_int(n:int, interval:int):
        splitted = [hex(n)[2:][i:i + interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)]
        return [int(hex(unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 16)))[0]), 16) for i in splitted]

    try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            row=cursor.fetchval()
            row_list=[]
            while row is not None:
                row=cursor.fetchval()
                hex_int = int(row, 16)
                result_print = (convert_hex_to_int(hex_int, 4))
                result_float = [float("{0:.2f}".format((i) * 10 ** -2)) for i in result_print]
                row_list.append(result_float)
            print(row_list)
```

Please leave any comment if I miss something, thanks in advance. 
When I debugged it, it shows something like this: 
[Debugged screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD1Od.png)

*sorry I had to attach the image as it is the debugged screen and i cant copy the code, and it had to be in link because i am a new user
**edit: i think it has to do with the use of .fetchval twice, but im not too sure

Comment: If `[hex(n)[2:][i:i + interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)] `  raises `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` then `n` is a `str`, not an `int`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the input is hex string, something like 0x94069206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line

```
[hex(n)[2:][i:i + interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)]
```

Results in

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Then `n` must not be an integer.

Observe, if `n` is `'0x94069206'`:

```
>>> hex('0x94069206')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

As  the code is taking slices of `n` it looks as if `n` needs to be a string, so the line should be:

```
splitted = [n[2:][i:i + interval] for i in range(0, len(n[2:]), interval)]
```

It  follows that the function signature should be

```
def convert_hex_to_int(n:str, interval:int)
```

On the other hand, if `n` is an `int` then the next line needs to be reworked.

Comment: Thanks! but, just wondering, 
if 
 ` row=cursor.fetchval()
   hex_int = int(row, 16)`
the first row, i am planning to get the row in string type, then, the second row, i am trying to get the data in the int data type with base 16, as it is hex input. So, would that be int?